# Read Only user's access getting removed automatically in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have created a read only user per below commands:

```
CREATE ROLE test_dw WITH
    LOGIN
    NOSUPERUSER
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    NOINHERIT
    NOREPLICATION
    CONNECTION LIMIT -1
    PASSWORD 'test@2021';
grant usage on schema view_test to test_dw;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA view_test TO test_dw;
```

This users access is getting removed automatically after few days and gives error "permission denied for schema view_test". then i grant access again using above 2 grant commands and then it starts working. but after few days again access gets removed automatically..
What may be the reason for this and how to fix this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where the objects dropped and newly (re)created by any chance? Did you set the default permissions of the schema so that the user gets access to new objects?

Comment: Postgres will not remove those grants by itself. There must be a script or something similar in your environment that resets this.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.. how i can set the default permissions of the schema so that the user gets access to new objects?

Comment: Yes, seems that schema is getting removed and recreated.. then how we can grant permanent read only user to this schema view in this case?